# React context; child component not rerendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context, react-functional-component

I may be misunderstanding how react context work in general, but how I think it should work goes like this:

I have a main app that has the Context provider as following

```
export default function app(){
   return <contextObj.Provider value={Complex Object with multiple properties...}>
     <Main/>
   </contextObj.Provider>
}
```

My main app is as follows

```
export default function main(){
   //Have imported the context class and am using it
   let store = React.useContext(myContext)
   
   return <React.Fragment> 
     <comp1 max={store.valueX} />
     <comp2 />
   </React.Fragment>
}
```

Inside of comp2, modify valueX inside of the context objext

```
export default function comp2(){
   //Have imported the context class and am using it
   let store = React.useContext(myContext)

   return <buttonComp onClick={()=>store.valueX=3} />
}
```

So in theory comp1 should receive the updated value and re-render?
This is where I'm stuck, as altering the context property isn't causing my comp1 to re-render.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like normal component state, you can't just directly mutate (assign to) the value of the context. You'll need to contain the value in state and pass down a callback to change that state (or use `useDispatch` for example):

```
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState({
    /* Complex Object with multiple properties */
  });

  const updateX = (newX) =>
    setValue((prevValue) => {
      return { ...prevValue, valueX: newX };
    });

  return (
    <contextObj.Provider value={{ ...value, updateX }}>
      <Main />
    </contextObj.Provider>
  );
}

export default function Comp2() {
  //Have imported the context class and am using it
  let store = React.useContext(myContext);

  return (
    <ButtonComp
      onClick={() => {
        store.updateX(3);
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

You'll probably want to move the state and the callbacks into a component specifically made for this - e.g. `MyContextProvider` which just contains the state and wraps its children in `MyContext.Provider`.

```
export function MyContextProvider({ initialValue, children }) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);

  const updateX = (newX) =>
    setValue((prevValue) => {
      return { ...prevValue, valueX: newX };
    });

  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={{ ...value, updateX }}>
      {children}
    </MyContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <MyContextProvider
      initialValue={/* Complex object with multiple properties */}
    >
      <Main />
    </MyContextProvider>
  );
}
```

However, if you're deriving your complex object with multiple properties inside `App`, it may be easier to just use the `Context.Provider` directly like in my first example.

Also, remember to always [capitalize your components' names](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html):

> **Note: Always start component names with a capital letter**.
>
> React treats components starting with lowercase letters as DOM tags.
> For example, `<div />` represents an HTML div tag, but `<Welcome />`
> represents a component and requires `Welcome` to be in scope.
>
> To learn more about the reasoning behind this convention, please read
> [JSX In Depth](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, i'll try this out and update in due time if it works! I'm relatively new to this so do bear with me !

Answer (score 1):

you should not mutate directly the context inside the children.

rather you should call a function/ reducer which will mutate the context.

what is happening right now, you are modifying one value, "valueX" inside an object "store" (the object is your context). For react the object still lives on the same memory location, so no change is detected.

cbr already answered correctly what you should rather do.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, i'll try this out and update in due time if it works! I'm relatively new to this so do bear with me !