# React Context Consumer not changing reactively or rerendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state, react-state-management

I have an odd situation where a state variable is updating successfully in one component but not in the other. I'm successfully changing the `state`, because I can see it reflected in the component where I'm triggering a `dispatch`. But in another component that is wrapped in the same `Provider`, I see no changes.

Other Stack Overflow answers seem to mostly recommend [not directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63631245/react-context-child-component-not-rerendering) [mutating state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69456314/react-changing-state-in-context-not-rerendering-dom), but here I'm not doing that - I'm dispatching an action to update the state, similar to what you'd see in Redux syntax.

[CodeSandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-sea-f3j1i?file=/src/TeaCard.js)

TeaSettingsContext.tsx

```
const TeaSettingsContext = createContext<{ state: State; dispatch: Dispatch } | undefined>(undefined);

const teaSettingsReducer = (state: State, action: Action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TeaSettingsActions.ChooseTea: {
      return { ...state, chosenTea: action.payload };
    }
    case TeaSettingsActions.ChangeStrength: {
      return { ...state, desiredStrength: action.payload };
    }
    default: {
      throw new Error(`Unhandled action type: ${action.type}`);
    }
  }
};

export function TeaSettingsProvider({
  children,
}: TeaSettingsProviderProps): Context {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(teaSettingsReducer, {
    chosenTea: {},
    desiredStrength: 0.5,
  });
  return (
    <TeaSettingsContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
      {children}
    </TeaSettingsContext.Provider>
  );
}

export const useTeaSettingsContext = (): TeaSettingsContext => {
  const context = useContext(TeaSettingsContext);
  if (context === undefined) {
    return;
  }
  return context;
};
```

Here's the "successful" component:

Home.tsx

```
<TeaSettingsProvider>
  <StrengthSlider />
</TeaSettingsProvider>
```

StrengthSlider.tsx

```
export default function StrengthSlider(): ReactNode {
  const { state, dispatch } = useTeaSettingsContext();
  console.log(state.desiredStrength) // logs the increment on each press.

  const incrementStrength = () => {
    dispatch({
      payload: state.desiredStrength + 0.1,
      type: "change-strength",
    });
  };

  return (
    <Box position="relative" w="100%">
      <Button title="Press" onPress={incrementStrength} />
      <Text>{state.desiredStrength}</Text>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

...and the unsuccessful re-render happens in this component:

TeaPage.tsx

```
const Component = () => {
    if (type === "tea") {
      return data.map((teaObj) => (
        <TeaCard id={teaObj.id} teaData={teaObj.data} key={teaObj.id} />
      ));
    }
  };

  return (
    <TeaSettingsProvider>
      <Component />
    </TeaSettingsProvider>
  );
```

TeaCard.tsx

```
export function TeaCard({ id, teaData }: TeaCardProps): ReactNode {
  const { state, dispatch } = useTeaSettingsContext();
  console.log(state.desiredStrength); // this always logs the starting value of 0.5 and doesn't log each time I press the button above.
// ...
}
```

FYI: Based my code on Kent C Dodds' article: https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstood a little how context works.

Basically (as [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider) suggest):

> Every Context object comes with a Provider React component that allows
> consuming components to subscribe to context changes.
>
> The Provider component accepts a value prop to be passed to consuming
> components that are descendants of this Provider. One Provider can be
> connected to many consumers. Providers can be nested to override
> values deeper within the tree.
>
> All consumers that are descendants of a Provider will re-render
> whenever the Provider’s value prop changes. The propagation from
> Provider to its descendant consumers (including .contextType and
> useContext) is not subject to the shouldComponentUpdate method, so the
> consumer is updated even when an ancestor component skips an update.

On short when you create a provider with a value you are able to access that information from multiple consumers (that need to be children of that provider). So far so good.

**Except:**
`Home.tsx` and `TeaPage.tsx` both initialize a different instance of the context (so each one has it's own provider).
In order to fix this you should only create one provider in a component that is parent of both `Home` and `TeaPage`.

React context is not working as redux (where you have a global store that you can access from everywhere). It rather give you the option to create a context (with reusable data) for a big component (to consume in the children).

Also please notice the last quoted paragraph from the beginning: basically when the context changes this cause all consumers to re-render (which might sometimes lead to some performance issues) so use it wisely. [Here](https://medium.com/@ryanflorence/react-context-and-re-renders-react-take-the-wheel-cd1d20663647) is a short article about this.

Comment: Ah okay. I originally had it all in `AppContext` that kind of provided a global state, but caused re-rendering and performance issues because other state values (i.e. not the ones in this context provider) were large and contained images etc.. So could I do something like wrap my `Routes` component (which contains both `Home` and `TeaPage`) in the `TeaSettingsProvider`? Then it should update `desiredStrength` and `chosenTea` without affecting the other variables that are large and slow-to-load, right?

Comment: Yes. Additionally:  if  you need multiple values in different places is better to create multiple separate context to prevent unnecessary re-rendering. Also in a specific case I ended up moving some data to the store and some in normal states to improve performance. So keep an eye out for this too in general.

Comment: But if you have a global state and no reason to avoid using it for this case I would rather go for global state in your case. This is not mandatory and context should work. But I think context is suited rather for updating the hole app (like changing the language or the theme), or for a specific large component with lots of children that need to use a context and is not worth to keep in global state since is for a very specific part of the code. You can also read in the provided react docs their recommendation (at the beginning of the article)